# How do I understand why the reading classlist part is null?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a button in a website to hide/show my slides, and replace it with a different component. I did it before and it worked out, so I thought a similar code would work but it doesn't.

Here is the html of my button:

```
<li><div class="behandlung-btn">Meine Behandlung</div></li>
```

And here is the html of the start of sliders:

```
<div class="sliders hideContent">
  <div class="slider home-slider clearfix" data-auto-play="8000">
```

Of course I closed the tag but since it's pretty long I didn't want to paste it all.

And here is the vanilla JS I tried:

```
   let showMoreBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".behandlung-btn");
  showMoreBtn.forEach((eachBtn) => {
    let textContainer = eachBtn.parentNode;
    let contentBox = textContainer.querySelector(".sliders").classList;
    eachBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (contentBox.contains("showContent")) {
        contentBox.remove("showContent");
        contentBox.add("hideContent");
        eachBtn.innerHTML = `<h12>ZEIG WENIGER</h12>`;
      } else {
        contentBox.add("showContent");
        contentBox.remove("hideContent");
        eachBtn.innerHTML = `<h12>ZEIG MEHR</h12>`;
      }
    });
  });
```

But it still says

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
at index.html:436:65
at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
at index.html:434:19
```

I know there are a lot of questions in Stackoverflow about this typeError and I checked them out, but still couldn't understand where the problem is, and also I'm a bit overwhelmed. Please help me out.

Thanks for the help in advance people!

Comment: Glad you got an answer. I’d like to share some suggestions, if you don’t mind. Your “button” currently only works with mouse, not with keyboards or voice control. That’s a big issue for users with disabilities. Use real `<button>` whenever you can. `<h12>` is not a valid HTML element. You should replace all the `let` by [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const). Check out [the Disclosure Pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/disclosure/) for a quality example of your pattern, most notably the `aria-expanded` attribute.

Comment: Also [the `<summary>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary) might be interesting to you.

Comment: Ah! I am still a beginner, I make a lot of mistakes. But I learn from them! I appreciate your help, thank you so much. Also now I understood what does that "for All" mean in your profile. I definitely need to ponder about what will that button actually do in real life. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no element with `.sliders` class inside the `textContainer` element which is the parent of the `button` whose class `behandlung-btn`

You need to use `document` instead.

```
let contentBox = document.querySelector(".sliders").classList;
```

Comment: So is the problem about eachBtn.parentNode? Do you know what can I use instead of parentNode?

Comment: You didn't share your HTML markup, so I don't know what is the structure of your app, or what is the point you want to achieve, but yes the issue is here.

Comment: Alright, I'm pasting the navigation bar, where the button is and the sliders I want to hide and replace in the question.
`

Comment: I update the answer, please check.

Comment: Ah, alright. It seems I parentNode is unusable if they're not in the same parent div. Thank you so much!